# representing µs in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I'm parsing a csv, and writing part of its contents to a xls file using `xlwt`

Every time µs pops up in the original file, I get a UnicodeDecodeError from `xlwt`:

```
  File "C:\SW_DevSandbox\E2\FlightTestInstrumentation\ICDforFTI\ICDforFTI.py", line 243, in generateICD
    icd.write(icdLine,icdTitle.index('Unit'),entry['Unit'])
  File "C:\espressoE2\tools\OpenVIB\1.2\python\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1030, in write
    self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
  File "C:\espressoE2\tools\OpenVIB\1.2\python\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 240, in write
    StrCell(self.__idx, col, style_index, self.__parent_wb.add_str(label))
  File "C:\espressoE2\tools\OpenVIB\1.2\python\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 326, in add_str
    return self.__sst.add_str(s)
  File "C:\espressoE2\tools\OpenVIB\1.2\python\lib\site-packages\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 24, in add_str
    s = unicode(s, self.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I think the root problem is the following:

In python 3, I can easily represent µs:

```
>>> '\xb5s'
'µs'
>>>
```

In python 2, apparently not:

```
>>> '\xb5s'
'\xb5s'
>>> u'\xb5s'
u'\xb5s'
>>> unicode('\xb5s')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> unicode('\xb5s','utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\espressoE2\tools\OpenVIB\1.2\python\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: invalid start byte
>>>
```

Edit: `print u'\xb5s'` works in Python 2, thanks @cdarke. But print does not solve the problem, it's not an internal representation I can then feed to `xlwt`.
end of Edit.

**So how can I represent µs in Python 2?**

Notepad++ displays the csv file fine, with µs. The "Encoding" menu shows it's encoding as "ANSI", and if I change to "UTF-8" I start seeing the "B5" all over the text. 
Python 2 Unicode has no encoding called "ANSI".
Is there a Python 2 Unicode encoding equivalent to what Notepad++ calls "ANSI"?

Comment: On python 2.7 I `print u'\xb5s'` and it displays fine in a terminal on OS X, so it might be the encoding used by the terminal system.  Which environment are you using?  Since you are on Windows, you should be aware that `cmd.exe` does not support Unicode.

Comment: @cdarke ´print u'\xb5s'´ works in my python 2 as well, thanks for that clue. My original attempt did not use the print statement.

Comment: "ANSI" encoding is probably "Windows-1252". Try using `'cp1252'` encoding, if it won't help `'latin_1'`.

Comment: @Nikita icdWorkbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="cp1252") did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ANSI` in Notepad is the native locale for Windows.  If you are using US Windows that locale is `cp1252`.  Your file is probably encoded in `cp1252` and not `utf8`.  If you are using another version of Windows, `locale.getpreferredencoding()` will tell you what Windows considers `ANSI`.

```
>>> '\xb5s'.decode('cp1252')
u'\xb5s'
```